# Getting one row while using aggregation function in case of transpose rows to column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

When i am transposing rows to column i am getting only one value which is max, not able to display multiple value.Below is my code

```
SELECT  trans_no,
MAX(CASE WHEN fld_tag = 21 AND FLD_ORD='1' THEN FLD_VAL END)FIELD_21
FROM table_1 where trans_no ='100' GROUP BY trans_no;
```

Output should be like this

```
trans_no | field_21
  100    | 20015
  100    | 20016
  100    | 20017
```

but currently i am getting only one value which is max,

```
 trans_no | field_21
  100     | 20017
```

How to display all the values

Comment: `MAX()` returns the maximum, that is the largest, value of the column. That is what your code says and what it does. It is not clear what you are transposing. So you need to post some sample data from `table_1` and you need to explain what output you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

You may get this output by using `pivot`:

```
select * from
( 
 select trans_no, case when fld_tag = 21 and fld_ord = '1' then fld_val end field_21
   from table_1
)
 pivot
(
 avg(trans_no) trans_no
 for trans_no in (100)   
)
order by field_21;
```